# complex SQL query - one table

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I am new to SQL.

I was wondering if there is a way to form a complex (I think) query of a certain form, regarding a single table - or a simple query for the same effect.

- Let's say I have a table of voice actor candidates, with different attributes (columns) - name and characteristics.
- Let's say I have two different actor evaluators (Stewie and Griffin), and all the candidates were evaluated by minimum one of them (one, or both). The evaluators evaluate the actors, and the table is built.
- The rows in the table are per-evaluation, not per-person, meaning that some candidates have two separate rows, one from each evaluation.
- The evaluator's name is also an attribute, a column.

**Can I make a query that will choose all candidates that were evaluated by both evaluators?** (and let's say show all these rows, an even number then)

(*There is no attribute "evaluated by both"* - that's the core)

I think it should find all rows with evaluator Stewie, then search the entire table for rows with the corresponding candidates' names, and get those with evaluator Griffin.

### Summary

A table with people - names and characteristics. One or two rows per person. Each row was filled according to a different observer. There is an attribute "Is Nice". How to find all people that were observed by two observers, one marked "Yes" and one "No" under "Is Nice"?

### Update

It will take me some time to check all the answers (as not enough experience yet), and I will update what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make a query that will choose all candidates that were evaluated
> by both evaluators?
> (and let's say show all these rows, an even number then)

There are multiple ways to do this. You can check the existence of other evaluator's evaluation, using `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Candidate AS C1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Candidate AS C2 WHERE C1.id = C2.id AND C1.evaluator != C2.evaluator)
```

Or, you could join the table to itself: (The checks for evaluators should be changed as appropriate)

```sql
SELECT C1.candidateName FROM Candidate AS C1 JOIN Candidate AS C2 USING (id) WHERE C1.evaluator = Stewie AND C2.evaluator = Griffin
```

> How to find all people that were observed by two observers, one marked
> "Yes" and one "No" under "Is Nice"?

For this one, you add another condition to the queries above, that checks if one evaluation was "Yes" and the other one was "No".

Answer (score 0):

This is surely not the best way to write it, but my first thought is

```
SELECT * FROM evaluations 
 WHERE PrName IN (
         SELECT PrName 
           FROM evaluations 
          WHERE IsNice ='No') 
   AND PrName IN (
          SELECT PrName 
            FROM evaluations 
           WHERE IsNice ='Yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `group by` and `having`. SInce a person cannot have more than two rows, and there are only two distinct possible values for `isnice` (yes or no), we can phrase the query as:

```
select name
from people
group by name
having max(isnice) <> min(isnice)
```

This filter names that have (at least) two different values in `isnice`. Starting from the above assumptions, this is sufficient to ensure that that person was evaluated more than once, and that `isnice` has (at least) two different values.

Answer (score 0):

So, I read the problem very carefully, and came up with my own solution.
Please verify the code below if this is what you were really asking for?

```
--Create Candidates Table
CREATE TABLE tbl_candidates
(
    c_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    c_name VARCHAR(30),
)

--Create Evaluators Table
CREATE TABLE tbl_evaluators
(
    e_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    e_name VARCHAR(30),
)

--Create Evaluations Table
CREATE TABLE tbl_evaluations
(
    ee_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    ee_title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ee_remarks VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ee_date date NOT NULL,
    c_id INT FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES tbl_candidates(c_id) NOT NULL,
    e_id1 INT FOREIGN KEY (e_id1) REFERENCES tbl_evaluators(e_id) NOT NULL,
    e_id2 INT FOREIGN KEY (e_id2) REFERENCES tbl_evaluators(e_id),
    IsNice VARCHAR(4)

)

--Populate data & check to verify

INSERT INTO tbl_candidates (c_name) VALUES ('Sam') , ('Smith')
SELECT * FROM tbl_candidates

INSERT INTO tbl_evaluators (e_name) VALUES ('Stewie'),('Griffin')
SELECT * FROM tbl_evaluators


INSERT INTO tbl_evaluations 
(ee_title,ee_remarks,ee_date,c_id,e_id1,e_id2,IsNice) 
VALUES 
('Some Title','Some Comment','2020-6-12',1,1,NULL,'No'),
('Some Title','Some Comment','2020-6-12',2,1,2,'Yes'),
('Some Title','Some Comment','2020-6-12',3,2,NULL,'No')


--finally comparing whether we have the matching data of our input vs tables combined data display
select * from tbl_evaluations

select ee_id,ee_title,c_name,ee_remarks,e1.e_name,e2.e_name,ee_date,IsNice from tbl_evaluations ee
left join tbl_candidates c on c.c_id = ee.c_id left join tbl_evaluators e1 on e1.e_id = ee.e_id1 left join tbl_evaluators e2 on e2.e_id = ee.e_id2
```

See the result proof :

[image]